# How to Run Test cases one by one in Visual Studio

Tags: automated-tests, mstest, msdn

I wanted to run the test cases one at a time through the automation. How to do that through the command prompt?

I wanted to run "AccountGroupTests"

[image]

Comment: Doesn't simply executing the tests already run them "one by one"?  What specifically is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: @David how to run that through the automation I am very  much new to the concept. I don't want to run any test case manually by right clicking and run selected

Comment: Why this is related to TFS? It seems only related to VS. To run all the tests automation, you could create an **ordertest** with select "continue on failure" for all this test runs. Then use mstest command such as `MSTest /TestContainer:OrderedTest1.orderedtest`

Answer (score 0):

To run all the tests automation, you could create an **ordertest** with select "*continue on failure*" for all this test runs.

Then use mstest command such as `MSTest /TestContainer:OrderedTest1.orderedtest` to do the automation.

Detail steps about how to create oardertest, please refer this tutorial in MSDN: [Create an Ordered Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631(v=vs.120).aspx)

[image]

Comment: I have tried this but not able to create the ordered test case means I am not able to add the test cases in the orders test list.. Could you please help me out

Comment: @UnmeshGhatbandhe Did you follow the tutorial proved above , just need to right click add and select order test. Detail step please see my update screenshot.

Comment: Patrick-MSFT Please find Images I have uploaded https://ufile.io/gw927 https://uploadfiles.io/f14q7  https://uploadfiles.io/6oi7x and wanted to automate the test cases. I think i have not explained properly... I do wanted to Run AccountGroupTests.... Images Contain code and classes and the hierarchy...

Comment: @UnmeshGhatbandhe Which seems to be a third-party testframework. Have no idea with this, you could ask this in the test related  MSDN forun or add test related tag get more attention.